# What are our responsibilities if we bundle a freely available third-party driver with our software?

Tags: software, licensing

Let's say I'm producing and selling a physical device. This device can optionally be connected to a computer via USB. We provide a configuration program, free of charge, which anyone can freely download from our website. Most of the time this works out of the box. However, on some computers, the device is not recognized, so the user has to manually install the driver. An advanced user can look up the device type, recognize what it is, go to the website of the manufacturer of the USB communicator chip, and download the driver for free. However, to make it easier for the novice user, we'd like to include this driver into our own installer. After the installation of our software is complete, the option "install drivers" comes up, and if selected, then the installer program of the third-party driver is called, which presents its own license agreement, etc. So it is absolutely clear that we don't claim it as our own, we don't intend to infringe their intellectual property.

The license text of the driver says *"You may redistribute to your customers the Licensed Software [...].  Your redistribution may be in any form, including physical media and Internet downloads."* (the removed parts discuss what parts of the licensed software we are allowed to modify and which we aren't, and this is moot because we didn't modify any part of it).

Does this mean we don't have to do anything? Or do we need a chapter in our own license agreement which states that we included a third party driver and that third party driver belongs to XYZ?

Comment: The license text may also stipulate some other things, such as that you must provide your users with a copy of the license. Other than that, it would seem that the license grants you the right to redistribute the driver software in the way that you want, so long as you meet any conditions that the license imposes on such redistribution. If you are unsure, though, it might be advisable to contact the manufacturer to check that your intended redistribution of the licensed software falls within the terms of the license.

Comment: "What are our responsibilities" - responsibilities to _whom_ ? You have responsibilities to the copyright owner and responsibilities to your end customer.